# How to enable Prometheus internal metrics?

Tags: prometheus, metrics

I want to monitor Prometheus service using prometheus.

Localy I have following docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  grafana:
    build: './config/grafana'
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./grafana:/var/lib/grafana
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    networks:
      monitoring:
        aliases:
          - grafana
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./config/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - ./prometheus:/prometheus
    networks:
      monitoring:
        aliases:
          - prometheus
networks:
  monitoring:
```

When I start prometheus I can visit http://localhost:9090/ to see UI and it works but there are no metrics. To see metrics I need to do 2 thisngs:

1. force Prometheus to expose metrics
2. Configure prometheus to listen metrics

Second step is clear for me but I don't understand how to force Prometheus to expose metrics.

Could you please explain that ?

Comment: Your question lacks clarity. Where did you read that "To see metrics I need to do 2 things"? I think this is untrue. When the Prometheus server is running (on `9090`), you should be able to browse its metrics on `http://localhost:9090/metrics` without further configuration. Prometheus has extensive [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs) and I encourage you to consider that to learn how to configure Prometheus to "scrape targets"

Comment: @DazWilkin wow http://localhost:9090/metrics works. Could you point me out to the corresponding part of documentation please ? I can't find

Comment: You'll want to add a [`scape_config`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) section to the `prometheus.yml`

Comment: Yes, I know it, I've already done it and it works properly. But i can't find anything about   Prometheus own metrics in documentation

Comment: Ah, I'm unsure if they're explicitly documented. The `/metrics` exposition should be reasonably descriptive by using the `HELP` comments.

Comment: @DazWilkin help of what product ? how can I find it ?

Comment: The metrics (e.g. http://localhost:9090/metrics) are somewhat (!) self-documenting. Each metrics includes 2 comments: `# HELP` is a text description and `# TYPE` shows the type (`counter`, `gauge`, `historgram`, `summary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks  @DazWilkin

by default Prometheus own metrics are available on

```
localhost:9090/metrics
```